# Converting a List of pojo Class to a Jdom Tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, jdom

I have  a POJO class call `LEVEL` & his  class diagramm like this:

```
    0,1
    ------------|
    |           |
    |           |
   \|/          |   
  level-<>-------
```

In other words this:

```
public class Level
{
 private int id;
 private int label;
 private Set<Level> labels;
 private Level parent;
 ...
 }
```

I have  a method who retrieve from the database ALL the level in a `List<Level>`.

I want for the jdom representation(using `org.jdom` api) a Tree (like a tree for your directories) like this

```
LEVEl 1
+++LEVEL 2
++++++LEVEL 3
LEVEL 4
LEVEL 5
```

I know the algorithm have to be recursive.

Do u have any solution ? Any tool to convert to java class to a jdom tree?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any library that would do exactly what you ask for.

---

Your class Level is correct, but not the only option. You could also **add a property `Set<Level> children`**. You could keep the `parent` link or not (bi-directional relationship, or Many-To-One).

That might make your tree structure more natural...

---

For example, if you were **using an ORM** like Hibernate, your could just find the first level instance (in the list you receive from Hibernate), and you would already have your tree, simply ignore other instances.

---

Otherwise, an algorithmic solution could be:

1. have all your instances in an `unprocessed` list
2. find all instances of the unprocessed, that have no parent ; add them to your tree, delete them from unprocessed.
3. loop on the following :

   - find all instances of the unprocessed, that have their parent in the tree (if the tree doesn't have an efficient implementation of `contains`, you can use a temporary Set for this).
   - add them to your tree, delete them from unprocessed.